# Microsoft Edge disregarding height in SVG when using <object> and <img>

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, microsoft-edge

I have an SVG image which is designed to respond to various widths appropriately, but which should have a fixed height.

In every browser I've tested, including IE11, the SVG is embedded honouring the `width` and `height` attributes in the `<svg>` element.

The SVG specifies a height (in pixels), which every browser except Edge uses.
Edge simply sets the height of the SVG to 150 pixels.

Please see the following Plunk for a repro (my actual SVG is more complex, but relies on embedded, readable text):

http://embed.plnkr.co/maFExXewuzonQJ6y4uRr/

---

## Repro

#### Chrome

Here's how it's supposed to look (Chrome 67):
[image: Rendering of SVG in Chrome 67]

---

#### Edge

Here's what Edge does (38.14393.2068.0):
[image]

---

## viewBox

Common wisdom appears to be that to fix weird scaling issues in Edge, you should specify a viewBox on the top-level SVG. Unfortunately, that either preserves the aspect ratio of the wrong thing (cropping or shrinking important stuff), or *stretches* the contents of the SVG, including text - depending on the `meetOrSlice` componentn of `preserveAspectRatio`.

---

## Options

I can't embed the raw SVG directly into the page, as it's generated dynamically by a server-side script and embedded into a CMS (which I can't write script for).

The generated height also varies, and can't be included in the HTML object embed code. This is because the SVG may include a variable number of lines of text.

It also has to be an `<object>` for interactivity.

What I can tweak is:

- the generated SVG;
- the properties of the `<object>` element;
- the HTML surrounding the `<object>` (although minimizing this is preferred);

I can also include some CSS, and possibly some JS although I'd rather avoid a scripting solution if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic JavaScript solution that appears to work in Edge.

`<object>` elements have a [`contentDocument` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement), through which the SVG can be accessed directly, in its DOM representation.

Accessing the SVG DOM means we can pull out the attributes directly out of the XML, and poke them onto the `<object>` element.

So, for example (with a single `<object>` element):

```js
{
    let o = document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];
    o.onload = function() {
        o.height = o.contentDocument.rootElement.getAttribute('height');
    }
}
```

It would be lovely to find a solution that doesn't rely on JS though

Further, this approach does *not* appear to work if the SVG is loaded cross-domain.